# Bluetooth headphones not being recognized after removing device

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, headphones, 23.10

First of all, I use Lubuntu 23.10

I paired my Bluetooth headphones to my laptop using `bluetoothctl pair` and it worked, but every time I'd turn on my Laptop, the headphones would automatically connect to the laptop even if they were already connected to another device, so I decided to remove them from my added Bluetooth devices using `bluetoothctl remove`, but now when I try to add them back, the Bluetooth Manager doesn't detect them, however it does detect other devices such as my  phone. The headphones work properly on other devices but not on my laptop.

Using `bluetoothctl scan on` doesn't work either.

What may the problem be?

Comment: Are the headphones in pairing mode when they are not detected?